# system.file not exported error

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-package

I get the error when I try to use devtools:system.file()
Error : object 'system.file' is not exported by 'namespace:devtools' while buiding my package.

In my roxygen2 I have added the following line

```
 #' @importFrom devtools system.file
```

but I get this error. Where I should I do this export?

I had to try this because the 'Build check' of  examples section of my roxygen2 lines fail

```
  pathToFile <- system.file("data",package = "yorkr")
  getBatsmanDetails(team="India",name="Kohli",dir=pathToFile)
```

with this  error

```
  Warning in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :cannot open compressed file   
:/Users/Ganesh/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCQxCAB/RLIBS_2c8411c225be/yorkr/data/Ind ia-BattingDetails.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
   Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
```

The system.file() seems to call the base version instead of devtools version

Please let me know what has to be done

Comment: system.file isn't part of devtools. It's part of base R. See `?system.file`

Comment: The package doesn't actually export a definition for `system.file`. It attaches a new version to it's own namespace. The actual function name in `devtools` is `shim_system.file`. What are you actually trying to accomplish by including this importFrom?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have include examples in my package. While the code builds properly I need to run the examples in each source file. So I created a /data directory and have test data. I  use pathToFile <- system.file("data",package = "yorkr")
getBatsmanDetails(team="India",name="Kohli",dir=pathToFile) but this is invoking the base system.file and not picking up the package. I have been trying several things for hours based on my original question this morning. Would defintely appreciate help on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275404/issue-with-data-directory-in-r-package

Comment: Just tried > pathToFile <- shim_system.file("data",package = "yorkr")
 Error: could not find function "shim_system.file. What am I missing?

Comment: When I do ?shim_system.file() it brings up system.file(). How can I invoke the system.file from devtools rather than the one from base package. This is what I am struggling with for many hours

Comment: `devtools:::shim_system.file`